# Split a long SQL query inside a variable

Tags: python, pep8

Following the PEP8 guidelines, what would be the best practice to format a very long sql wistatement into a variable?

An example bellow, of how im splitting the variable:

```
var= "some value"
query = "select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h from a_very_long_tablename" +\
"where a_very_long_sql_statement='is_really_very_long' " +\
"or a_very_long_sql_statement='" + var + "' order by a"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a triple quoted string:

```
query= """\
select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h from a_very_long_tablename
where a_very_long_sql_statement='is_really_very_long'
or a_very_long_sql_statement='is_really_really_very_long'
"""
```

SQL is a whitespace-agnostic language, you can use newlines as well as spaces to delimit. The initial backslash escapes the first newline; it's a personal preference but not needed.

If you really don't want the newlines, put parenthesis around your string; no need to use `+` signs then as python will make it one long string for you:

```
query = (
    "select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h from a_very_long_tablename "
    "where a_very_long_sql_statement='is_really_very_long' "
    "or a_very_long_sql_statement='is_really_really_very_long'")
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code:

```
query = """
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
FROM a_very_long_tablename
WHERE a_very_long_sql_statement='is_really_very_long
OR a_very_long_sql_statement='is_really_really_very_long
"""
```

Comment: No need to put parenthesis around that.

Comment: Worked ! But im updating the question with an example using variables

Comment: just include the variable like below
query """ select bla bla bla %s""" % (var)

Answer (score 1):

After your edit, if you want to include your variable in the sql query.

```
query = """
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
FROM a_very_long_tablename
WHERE a_very_long_sql_statement='is_really_very_long
OR a_very_long_sql_statement= %s
""" % var
```

Comment: The OP *really* should use a prepared statement instead of string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Using a triple-quoted `'''` and **format** string is more readable.

```
var= "some value"

query = '''
select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h from a_very_long_tablename
where a_very_long_sql_statement='is_really_very_long'
or a_very_long_sql_statement="{var}" order by a
'''.format(var=var)
```